# How do I check a request body against a provided schema in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Suppose I want to forward only those requests whose bodies have valid schemas (JSON attributes match those that a service expects). How do I do it? What GPT suggests is suspiciously clumsy so I was wondering whether there's a better way

```java
// some routing function inside Spring Cloud Gateway code
        return spec -> spec
                .predicate(serverWebExchange -> serverWebExchange.getRequest()
                                                                  .getBody()
                                                                  // what's next?
                )
                .and()
                .path("/api/example")
                .uri("http://SOME_SERVICE");
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks at the read body predicate

Comment: @Community what details do I need to provide?